# Using LMC to solve algebraic equations

Tags: little-man-computer

I am getting stuck on writing a program for the following:

a<sup>2</sup> + (b x c).

There appears to be a problem with my loops, but I cannot solve it.

I can get a<sup>2</sup> and a multiplication, but when I try to combine the two, it just keeps asking for inputs over and over again.

Multiply:

```
        INP
        STA b
    INP STA c
   LOOP LDA c 
        BRZ ENDTHIS
        SUB ONE1
        STA c
        LDA ANS1
        ADD b
        STA ANS1
        BRA LOOP
ENDTHIS LDA ANS1 
        OUT
        SUB ANS1 
        STA ANS1
        HLT 
      b DAT
      c DAT 
   ONE1 DAT 1 
   ANS1 DAT 0
```

Square:

```
        INP
        STA a
        LDA a
        STA y
   LOOP LDA y
        BRZ END
        SUB ONE2
        STA y 
        LDA ANS2
        ADD a
        STA ANS2
        BRA LOOP
    END LDA ANS2 
        OUT 
        SUB ANS2
        STA ANS2
        HLT 
      a DAT
      y DAT 
   ONE2 DAT 1
   ANS2 DAT 0
```

But can't get them to work together

Comment: The first question: which programming language do you use? The second question: what **exactly** have you tried so far?

Comment: LMC using the Peter Higginson simulator

Comment: Multiply        
 INP
        STA b
        INP
        STA c
LOOP    LDA c
        BRZ ENDTHIS
        SUB ONE1
        STA c
        LDA ANS1
        ADD b
        STA ANS1
        BRA LOOP
ENDTHIS LDA ANS1
        OUT
        SUB ANS1
        STA ANS1
        HLT
b       DAT 
c       DAT 
ONE1    DAT 1
ANS1    DAT 0

Comment: Square
        INP 
        STA a
        LDA a
        STA y
LOOP    LDA y
        BRZ END
        SUB ONE2
        STA y
        LDA ANS2
        ADD a
        STA ANS2
        BRA LOOP
END     LDA ANS2
        OUT
        SUB ANS2
        STA ANS2 
        HLT
a       DAT
y       DAT
ONE2    DAT 1
ANS2    DAT 0

Comment: But cant get them to work together

Comment: This is what i have tried, I know I need to add in the '+' section at the end

Comment: INP
STA b
INP
STA c
LOOP    LDA c
BRZ ENDTHIS
SUB ONE1
STA c
LDA ANS1
ADD b
STA ANS1
BRA LOOP
ENDTHIS LDA ANS1
OUT
STA BXC
SUB ANS1
STA ANS1
INP 
STA a
LDA a
STA y
LOOP    LDA y
BRZ END
SUB ONE2
STA y
LDA ANS2
ADD a
STA ANS2
BRA LOOP
END     LDA ANS2
OUT
SUB ANS2
STA ANS2 
HLT
a       DAT
y       DAT
ONE2    DAT 1
ANS2    DAT 0
b       DAT 
c       DAT 
ONE1    DAT 1
ANS1    DAT 0
BXC     DAT

Comment: I am thinking it is having multiple LOOPs that is the issue - but unsure

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter that counts from 2 down to 0.

Pass the first input to *b* and *c*, and execute the multiplier part to the result.
Decrement the counter and if it is not zero yet, get the other two inputs in *b* and *c*, and execute the multiplier code again.

If the counter becomes zero, it means you processed all input and you can output the result.

```html
#input: 3 5 2
        INP   // a
        STA b // pass (a, a) to multiplier
        STA c

// add (b x c) to result
   loop LDA c 
   exit BRZ endloop
        SUB one 
        STA c
        LDA result
        ADD b 
        STA result 
        BRA loop

// decrement counter from 2 to 1 to 0
endloop LDA counter
        SUB one
        STA counter
        BRZ finish
         
        INP   // b
        STA b
        INP   // c
        STA c
        BRA loop // add (b x c) to result

 finish LDA result
        OUT
        HLT

      a DAT
      b DAT 
      c DAT 
    one DAT 1
counter DAT 2
 result DAT 0
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/trincot/lmc@v0.7/lmc.js"></script>
```